# UploadFile in zohocrm wso2esb connector

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm working with zohocrm wso2esb connector.

Here I'm trying to upload a file using `uploadFile` operation that is provided in zohocrm esb connector, in this operation i'm providing `apiUrl`, `accessToken`, `scope`, `moduleType` and `id`.

The problem is that I'm not clear which `id` to provide in the `id` field and also stuck with how and where to attach the file (to be uploaded in zohocrm) in uploadFile opeartion.